# How to implement email address like blue background in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I want to implement a blue background around a couple of words to group them together -- looks just like the email address in the default iPhone email client. (see attachment).

Does anybody know how to do that?!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [JSTokenField](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField) it looks very cool.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Both are very good. But I'll accept Aravindhanarvi's since it's easier to implement. Thanks both of you.

Comment: Please don't give link only answers - links can break at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screen shot of the background image and make a image.png you needed, and use the following method

```
 UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
```

7.0 and 0.0 is depending on your image.png size.

Apple's sample code [UICatalog.app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710) is for your reference. search "stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth" in that project. It's an example for a button background image. good luck!